# Convert Oracle query to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Oracle query is:

```
select  t3.id, 
        t4.caption || '>' || t3.caption  
from (
    SELECT  t1.id as id, 
            (t2.caption || '>' || t1.caption) as caption, 
            t2.pid as pid  
    FROM ParentChild T1, ParentChild T2 
    WHERE T1.pid = T2.id(+)
) t3, 
(
    SELECT  t1.id as id, 
            (t2.caption || '>' || t1.caption) as caption, 
            t2.pid as pid  
    FROM ParentChild T1, ParentChild T2 
    WHERE T1.pid = T2.id(+)
) t4 
where t3.pid = t4.id(+);
```

Output:

```
ID                     T4.CAPTION||'>'||T3.CAPTION
---------------------- ---------------------------
4                      a>b>c>d                    
3                      >a>b>c                     
1                      >>a                        
2                      >a>b                       
5                      >a>e
```

I need the equivalent SQL Server query...

Comment: You Probably need to learn [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Well, Oracle old style left join should be replaced with proper explicit left join, and oracle `||` string concatenation should be replaced with `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following query;)

```
SELECT t3.id, t4.caption + '>' + t3.caption
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id as id, (t2.caption + '>' + t1.caption) as caption, t2.pid as pid 
    FROM ParentChild T1
    LEFT JOIN ParentChild T2
    ON T1.pid = T2.id) t3
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t1.id as id, (t2.caption + '>' + t1.caption) as caption, t2.pid as pid  
    FROM ParentChild T1
    LEFT JOIN ParentChild T2
    ON T1.pid = T2.id) t4 ON t3.pid = t4.id;
```

Comment: id (No column name)
1 NULL
2 NULL
3 NULL
4 a>b>c>d
5 NULL                                                     Am run this above query shown output like this

Comment: Is there the same data between two databases?